# Kendo Currency Format For Pie Chart

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

All i need to show my values with currency format with Pie Chart. I think i missed so i couldn't find a solution for this.

How must i handle this code?

```
  .Template("#= category #: #= value '{0:C}'#"))
```

Here is my Kendo chart:

```
            @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
.Name("chart3")
      .Title(title => title
                    .Text(@ViewBag.a)
        .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Top))
        .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(true)
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top))
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Pie(model => model.Count, categoryExpression: model => model.Name);


    })


.Theme("metro")
      .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
    .Visible(true)
                            .Template("#= category #: #= value '{0:C}'#"))
        .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDB"))

            )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do it like so:

```
.Template("#= category #: #= kendo.toString(value, 'c0')#"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i couldn't get Currency with this code.

Comment: ispanak you might need to convert your value to a float, It could be a string. I had to do this to get it to work."#=kendo.format('{0:C0}', parseFloat(value))#"